# Find application handlers?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, citrix, remoteobject

### Problem

I am attempting to find a *window object* handle inside a remote terminal that is run though Citrix Remote with ZenApp.  My problem is I can see the parent window of Citrix Remote but no children.  I have tried WinSpy, WFP Inspector, and a few other API spy utilities; none of which could view the Citrix Remote properties.

---

### Question

What can I do to view these objects though this remote terminal?

**EXAMPLE**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No utility will be able to see the window handles for an application run over Citrix.  The application is running on the Citrix server.  The Citrix remote client presents only an image of the screen on the the client application.

The window handles that you are looking for are on the Citrix server, not the client machine you are running from.

Comment: Make perfect sense.  So my only real option will be to log the click point.  Unless you know of a way to view server properties.

Comment: Or run your app inside the Citrix session.

Comment: @donovan Wish I could.

Answer (score 1):

You'll never be able to get the window handles, as they don't exist; however, you *may* be able to use UI Automation to get the accessibility properties (name, position, etc.)   Certainly this works for Windows Remote Desktop on Windows 8 & above; it may or may not work for Citrix.  It's worth a try.